# Numpy searchsorted not working as expected

Tags: python, numpy

It seems I'm doing something wrong with numpy's `searchsorted`. It always gives me the highest index (285) for any number greater than the smallest number (~0.001) of `ratios.values`. However if inserted at this position, it would clearly break the existing ordering within `ratios.values`.

```
>>> ratios = df.activity.value_counts(normalize=True)
>>> np.searchsorted(ratios.values, 0.06)
285
>>> np.searchsorted(ratios.values, 0.006)
285
>>> np.searchsorted(ratios.values, 0.001)
0
```

For 0.06 I'd expect the index 1 to be returned, since 0.06 should be placed in between the first and second element of `ratios.values`.

[image]

Comment: `searchsorted()` requires an array that's sorted in *ascending* order.

Comment: yes! that's it. i expected it to work both ways. i guess that's what happens if you don't read carefully enough. if you write an answer, i will mark it as accepted :)